# Springboot CSFR disabled forbids POST method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using the following HttpSecurity configuration in my application:

```
 http.csrf().disable().
            authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(maintenanceRequestMatcher).denyAll().                
            antMatchers("/public/**").permitAll().                
            antMatchers("/auth/**").authenticated().
            antMatchers("/auth/api/superadmin/**").hasAnyRole("SUPERADMIN").
            antMatchers("/auth/api/admin/**").hasAnyRole("SUPERADMIN","ADMIN").
            antMatchers("/auth/api/staff/**").hasAnyRole("SUPERADMIN","ADMIN","STAFF").
            antMatchers("/auth/api/standarduser/**").hasAnyRole("SUPERADMIN","ADMIN","STAFF","STANDARDUSER").
            anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();

  http.               
            formLogin().                
            loginProcessingUrl("/public/api/access/login/signin").
            successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler()).
            failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler()).                 
            permitAll().
```

The controller is defined as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/public/api/access/login")
public class SigninController
{     
 @Autowired
 private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;  

 @Autowired
 PlatformStatusService platformService;
 @PostMapping("signin")
 public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody LoginDTO logindto)
 { 
   try
   {
    authenticationManager
    .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(logindto.getUsername(), logindto.getPassword()));
   return new ResponseEntity<>("logged", HttpStatus.OK);
   }
   catch(AuthenticationException e)
   {
     return new ResponseEntity<>("failed", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN); 
   }         
 }      
}
```

I disabled csrf and I would allow any post method on "/public/" root. Then in Junit I write:

```
mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(("/public/api/access/login/signin")).characterEncoding("utf-8") 
                                            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dto)))              
                                            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

I receive a forbidden status error. Is there any error in the configuration?

Notes:
PUT method works, any other POST method work as well.

Answer (score 0):

removing loginProcessingUrl("/public/api/access/login/signin") helped.